# Nginx proxy_pass backend server sends 302 to client and redirects client to a backend IP

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a backend server with IP 192.168.1.10 port 8090 the nginx can reach this via example 10.0.0.10 which is then NATed to 192.168.1.10

nginx ----> 10.0.0.10 ----> 192.168.1.10

This works well in general but we are facing a specific problem here it seems with redirections.

The client goes to https://nginx/gateway and the connection is established and the backend server app now requires authentication so the backend server send a 302 redirect back to the client. What I notice in the client web browser is that the address changes and the client tries to establish a connection to http://192.168.1.10:8080  (auth service is located on a different port). The page fails to load as the client has no route to this destination.

My expectation is that nginx takes care of this redirect internally and is simply passing the content to the client using its own https://nginx address.

The config is simple:

```
        location / {
                proxy_pass "http://10.0.0.10:8090";
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
}
```

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: Your code looks ok. Can you try without using the `"`. So it will be `proxy_pass http://10.0.0.10:8090;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it didnt help :(

I found out that i can possibly do something like:
               proxy_intercept_errors on;
                recursive_error_pages on;
                error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;

location @handle_redirects {
       set $orig_loc $upstream_http_location;
       proxy_pass $orig_loc;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
}

But the backend still redirects to 192.168.1.10 which Nginx has no route to. Is there a way to actually rewrite the 302 location header that is coming from the backend?

Comment: If you have changed nginx configuration files, you have to reload nginx, to changes take effect. With `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: yes, thanks, this i know :)

Comment: Now i see your problem, you have a two process running,  a dynamic server page at: `http://192.168.1.10:8080` and a backend for authentication (let's say API) at: ` http://192.168.1.10:8090`. that's it?

Comment: Correct. They are reachable for Nginx via 10.0.0.10 but the backend server sends a redirect to 192.168.1.10 that it then tries to follow which isn't working.